# Would this be the most efficient way to return to a view controller from a detail view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Would this be the most efficient way to return to a view controller from a detail view?

```
    // back button method
-(IBAction)BtnBack_Clicked:(id)sender{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

At the moment it takes a 2 or 3 seconds to return to the list view (a table view with a list of rows) and I'm trying to figure out why this might be.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When the old view controller is displayed again, `viewWillAppear` is called, and I'm guessing that you are loading/reloading your table view in this method.  Start looking there for how to speed things up.

It could also be in the view controller that you are leaving, in `viewWillDisappear`, but since you mentioned a table view in the other, I'm guessing that's what the problem is.

If you want help in more than general terms, you will need to post some of the view controller code.

Comment: thanks! that helped a lot. I moved code out of viewWillAppear.